# How to get hidden price in amazon using python scraper

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, amazon-product-api

I want to create program that will scrape amazon product information and create a database.
This program I want to create for computer details automatic scraping, but when I started for checking price my program starts work badly. It's only checked product name and rarely product price.
My code for scraping.

```
from selectorlib import Extractor
import requests 
import json 
from time import sleep


# Create an Extractor by reading from the YAML file
e = Extractor.from_yaml_file('selectors.yml')

def scrape(url):  

    headers = {
        'dnt': '1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'referer': 'https://www.amazon.com/',
        'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    }

    # Download the page using requests
    print("Downloading %s"%url)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # Simple check to check if page was blocked (Usually 503)
    if r.status_code > 400:
        if "To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact" in r.text:
            print("Page %s was blocked by Amazon. Please try using better proxies\n"%url)
        else:
            print("Page %s must have been blocked by Amazon as the status code was %d"%(url,r.status_code))
        return None
    # Pass the HTML of the page and create 
    return e.extract(r.text)

# product_data = []
with open("urls.txt",'r') as urllist, open('output.json','w') as outfile:
    for url in urllist.read().splitlines():
        data = scrape(url) 
        if data:
            json.dump(data,outfile)
            outfile.write("\n")

# Formatting file

f = open("output.json", "r")
json_data = f.readlines()
tmp = ''.join(json_data)
tmp = tmp.replace('}\n{', '},\n{') # replace '}{' with '},{'
tmp = '[' + tmp + ']' # add brackets around it
v = open("output.json", "w")
v.write(tmp)
print(tmp) # print the tmp
v.close()
f.close()
```

selectors.yml

```
name:
    css: '#productTitle'
    type: Text
price:
    css: '#price_inside_buybox'
    type: Text
```

And for one site my program works.
**urls.txt**

> [https://www.amazon.com/GIGABYTE-Graphics-WINDFORCE-GV-N3080GAMING-OC-12GD/dp/B09QDWGNPG/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09QDWGNPG)

But for other it can give **price : null**.

> [https://www.amazon.com/Intel-i7-12700KF-Desktop-Processor-Unlocked/dp/B09FXKHN7M/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09FXKHN7M)

How can I parse a hidden price?